# Sequelize Average of Date Difference

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following (abstract) sequelize model:

```
{
  startTime: Date,
  endTime: Date,
}
```

Now I want to get the average duration of all existing entities. In SQL I'd model this like `SELECT AVG("end_time" - "start_time") FROM "MyTable";`. But I don't know how I can do this with sequelize.

I've made some attempts on using `sequelize.fn()` but did not come to a conclusion.

So my goal is to have something like:

```
MyModel.findAll({
  attributes: ['averageTime' <<< now what?]
});
```

Oh and I'm using PostgreSQL 9.6.

Best,
Philipp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `findAll` or `findOne` as they return instance(s) of the model and you need to get some scalar value.

Raw query can be used to do what you need like this:

```
sequelize.query(
  'SELECT AVG("end_time" - "start_time") FROM "MyTable"',
  { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT}
).then(function(result) {
    // process result here
})
```